# Is there a way to recover overwritten files/folders in AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I started working with AWS recently. The s3 bucket had version ID enabled I was copying files from one folder to other which lead to replacement of files with the same name. I tried run the following script (credit: stack overflow) to recover the files using the version ID and ran the script as follows:

sh script name bucket name folder name

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket $1 --prefix $2 --output text |
 grep "VERSION*" | while read obj
   do
       KEY=$( echo $obj| awk '{print $4}')
       VERSION_ID=$( echo $obj | awk '{print $8}')
       echo $KEY
       echo $VERSION_ID
       aws s3api delete-object --bucket $1 --key $KEY --version-id $VERSION_ID

   done
```

This did not recover data, could anyone give me any pointers or edits in th script which can help me undo the copy?

Comment: Was the bucket actually versioned? Does the AWS console show the old versions?

Comment: @jarmod yes versioning was enabled. I added the information to the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the as docs on [Restoring Previous versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RestoringPreviousVersions.html).

> One of the value propositions of versioning is the ability to retrieve
> previous versions of an object. There are two approaches to doing so:
>
> - Copy a previous version of the object into the same bucket
>
> The copied object becomes the current version of that object and all
> object versions are preserved.
>
> - Permanently delete the current version of the object
>
> When you delete the current object version, you, in effect, turn the
> previous version into the current version of that object.

Is the current version of your files the right one after running your delete script?

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest to use the S3 console to view versions.

You'll see a "latest version" drop-down menu when you click on a file. You can delete specific versions from there, or download specific versions.

[image: Show versions]

For example, you could delete the newer version that is "on top" of the old version to make the old version the current version.